# Twilight Zone Spinoffs?

Tags: the-twilight-zone

I've been watching the original *Twilight Zone* on Netflix, and it occurs to me that many of the individual premises of each episode could easily be adapted for their own series.

To anyone's knowledge did any episodes of the *Twilight Zone* become the premise for a series of its own? (Either officially or unofficially)

P.S. Not counting the awesome *Twilight Zone* reunion on *3rd Rock from the Sun*.

EDIT: I'd like to expand the question to include films also. By unofficially, I mean, creators of shows/films who have stated that some episode was their inspiration, or that the original material that was the basis for the TZ adaptation was also the basis for something else.

Comment: If you care to include *movies* inspired by Twilight Zone, there are a bunch of them.

Comment: @Robert: sure, go ahead.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Other than the two television revivals (on CBS in the 80s and UPN in 2002-3), there are no official television spin-offs of the series, though it could be said that any number of sci-fi shows had some influence from the series, especially in some of their episode plots.

There was a film in 1983 (which was essentially three classic episodes remade for the big screen), a radio series, and a whole plethora of merchandising spin offs such as comic books, board games, a pinball game, a video game and other books.  There is also rumor of another revival series to be produced by Leonardo DiCaprio.  Rumors initially said he wanted to make a feature film, but lately they've been saying tv series instead.

Comment: Your rumor may be related to "The Box" movie, it came from the episode "Button, Button" in the Twilight Zone. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Button,_Button_%28The_Twilight_Zone%29

Answer (score 0):

The episode "Cavender is Coming" starring Jesse White and Carol Burnett, largely a remake of "Mr. Bevis", was a back-door pilot for a series starring the titular guardian angel, played by White.

It was played a straight comedy, and was originally broadcast with a laugh track - the versions running on Netflix and on video collections have the track removed.